# Identify bricks, similar to LEGO without bottom tubes

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, 3rd-party

I have a box of bricks with some age, that I'm unable to identify.

They have some numbers on the inside which don't help and no identifying markings. I thought they could be by [Halsam](http://halsam.com/), however that is not the case.

[image: picture of non-LEGO bricks]